# How to download an image from a webpage feed with python

Tags: python, image, download

I'm a bit new to python and I'm trying to write a script that gets the first image from a feed (meaning this image is going to change ever few hours so I can't just use its url) and download it to a specified file.
This is what I worte so far

```py
import requests

res = requests.get('image_url')

with open('./folder/img.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)

print('Done!')
```

Instead of putting the image url directly like shown above, I want to make it so that it automatically gets an image from a website.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also, include examples of what you have already tried when compiling a new question.

Comment: Will do, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the requests module to get the web page then the BeautifulSoup4 one to parse it and finally using regular expressions to match any post/image urls

```py
import bs4, requests, re

res = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/')
page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

mo = [img for img in page.find_all('img', {'alt': 'Post image'})]

urlReg = re.compile(r'https://preview.redd.it/\w+.jpg?\S+')
links = urlReg.findall(str(mo))
```

I still have one probleme where sometimes the regex doesn't match any urls in the page even tho I'm pretty sure there's more than one in there and I have to run it again until it eventually finds one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the module requests 
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content
You can install it with this command: pip install requests

**EDIT**

Which website is it ?

Comment: It's a costum [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/kerdaloo/m/dankmemer/) feed

Comment: The first you should do is to get the url from the last image uploaded on the feed. To do that you can use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) which is a library that allow you to parse web pages (It's called web scraping).

Comment: Reddit has also a [api](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/). They've also created the [Python Reddit API Wrapper](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.21/pages/getting_started.html) which is a python wrapper for this api.

Comment: yes I ended up using bs4 and regular expressions even though I know it's not the best method to use here. Thanks.